# using bootstrap 4 sass variables to create new css helper classes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webpack, bootstrap-4, sass, scss-mixins

I'd like to create some color helper related classes, like in tailwind, where we can define elements colors with classes like `text-red-400` or `bg-gray-100`.

It's this kind of helper classes that I would like to create with Bootstrap 4. I noticed that the necessary variables already exist in the `_variables.scss` file:

```
$blue-100: tint-color($blue, 8) !default;
...
$indigo-100: tint-color($indigo, 8) !default;
...
and so on...
```

The goal would be to use all these available variables to create my color helper classes for `text`, `background` and `border`.

The problem is that I'm pretty new to **scss and webpack** and I have no clue how to achieve this or if it is even possible.

Any help would be apreciated.

Thank you all.